# Cross compiling Gotk3 App for Windows on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, go

I am trying to crosscompile my app on gotk3 (latest) for windows on Ubuntu 20.04. I use command:

`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/pkgconfig CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -x -v -tags gtk_3_24 -gcflags "-I/usr/include/" -ldflags "-H=windowsgui" -o main-windows-amd64.exe main.go`

But have error (with debug output):

```
github.com/gotk3/gotk3/glib
mkdir -p $WORK/b002/
cd /root/go/src/github.com/gotk3/gotk3/glib
pkg-config --cflags -- gio-2.0 glib-2.0 gobject-2.0 gio-2.0 glib-2.0 gobject-2.0 gio-2.0
pkg-config --libs -- gio-2.0 glib-2.0 gobject-2.0 gio-2.0 glib-2.0 gobject-2.0 gio-2.0
TERM='dumb' CGO_LDFLAGS='"-g" "-O2" "-lgio-2.0" "-lgobject-2.0" "-lglib-2.0"' /usr/lib/go-1.15/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/cgo -objdir $WORK/b002/ -importpath github.com/gotk3/gotk3/glib -- -pthread -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I $WORK/b002/ -g -O2 ./application.go ./connect.go ./gaction.go ./gactiongroup.go ./gactionmap.go ./gasyncresult.go ./gbinding.go ./gcancellable.go ./gfile.go ./gicon.go ./giostream.go ./glib.go ./glib_export.go ./glib_since_2_42.go ./glib_since_2_44.go ./glib_since_2_46.go ./glistmodel.go ./gmain_context.go ./gpermission.go ./gsimpleactiongroup.go ./gsource.go ./gvariant.go ./gvariantbuilder.go ./gvariantclass.go ./gvariantdict.go ./gvariantiter.go ./gvarianttype.go ./list.go ./menu.go ./notifications.go ./settings.go ./settings_backend.go ./settings_schema.go ./settings_schema_source.go ./slist.go
# github.com/gotk3/gotk3/glib
In file included from ./glib.go.h:31,
                 from /root/go/src/github.com/gotk3/gotk3/glib/application.go:6:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gi18n.h:23:10: fatal error: libintl.h: No such file or directory
   23 | #include <libintl.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

File ***libintl.h*** here: ***/usr/include/libintl.h***.

Looks like cgo missing include path. I tried add include path manualy with gcflags option but cgo ignores it. How I can get it working? Golang version - 1.15.8.

I know about this manual - https://onedev.net/post/940
but that archlinux image is too old and not working. New archlinux images at dockerhub is broken too at the moment.